# Comparison of Milliseconds in Maria DB Date Time

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

DB: 10.5.13-MariaDB-log

**Background**

```
Table : sample_table
Column : create_at(datetime), another_column (varchar)
```

Several rows are already in it.

Ex) create_at = 2022-07-29 07:19:09.0

**Then**

```
SELECT *
FROM sample_table
WHERE create_at = ‘2022-07-29 07:19:09.1234’
```

Then return result 1 row.

```
SELECT *
FROM sample_table
WHERE create_at = ‘2022-07-29 07:19:09.1234’
ORDER BY another_column;
```

Then return result 0 row;

I don’t know why.
Why difference return answers?

Comment: What datetype is create_at?

Comment: Order by won't make a difference and I don't believe your first query returns any rows. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=407ab033a09f3578bc5660f8f13d1534

Comment: Edit my question. It is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify a precision for your column - e.g.

```sql
ALTER TABLE sample_table ALTER COLUMN create_at DATETIME(4)
```

Comment: Yes, it can be solved, but I want to know why

Comment: Why what? By default the precision of a column is zero (if you do not explicitly specify one) - so DATETIME does not store fractional digits therefore they are considered `000....` when comparing with other DATETIME value which **has** fractional digits. Consequently, the comparison usually evaluates to FALSE - like in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The precision is marked as 0

The first example returns one row.
Then, in the second example, only order by was added, but why is there no return result?

Does the only addition of order by.
It make precision isn't 0?

Comment: Can you demonstrate the issue on DBfiddle or something like that?

Comment: Well, it was a problem at work. However, it doesn't happen when I made a db through docker separately. Thank you for your answer

Comment: If you can't reproduce the issue using the same MariaDB/MySQL version that you have at work - you can safely forget about it. If you can - you should file a bug.